# Split sentence into words and insert in 2d array

Tags: java

I have a String that I need to arrange in a 2d array across n columns. If the string has multiple words, I need to spread the words evenly across columns, that is have equal words per column. I can't figure out how to code this up.

```
public static void arrangeWords(String input) {
        String[] inputArr = input.split(" ");
        int length = inputArr.length;
        System.out.println("LENGTH " + length);
        int col = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(length));
        int row = (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(length));

        String[][] result = new String[row][col];
        System.out.println("ROW: " + row + " COL: " + col);

        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                if (k < inputArr.length) {
                    result[i][j] = inputArr[k];
                }
                k++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
    }
```

Comment: Should the number of columns `n` be the input parameter?

Comment: You  should include more details and clarify the problem. Provided code prints a char array and doesn't meet the discription in your question. A sample input along with the disired output might help to understand your intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the number of columns is an external input parameter, the 2D array may be created and populated using the words in the input string.
The words should be sorted by their length in descending order.

```java
static String[][] buildTable(String str, int n) {
    // prepare sorted array of words
    String[] words = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+"))
        .sorted(Comparator.<String>comparingInt(String::length).reversed())
        .toArray(String[]::new);
    // build the resulting 2D array
    String[][] res = new String[words.length / n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        res[i / n][i % n] = words[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Test:

```java
String str = "Apple is my favorite fruit because it is yummy";

Arrays.stream(buildTable(str, 3))
    .map(Arrays::toString)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
[favorite, because, Apple]
[fruit, yummy, is]
[my, it, is]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  public void test() {
    String inputStr = "Apple is my favorite fruit because it is";
    String[] words = inputStr.split(" ");
    int columns = (int) Math.sqrt(words.length);

    int c = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
      System.out.print(word + " ");
      c = c + 1;
      if (c == columns) {
        System.out.println("");
        c = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

The idea is that you get number of columns with square root of size. You add items to the column until the row is full and then you move to the next one.

Comment: This is not in a 2d array with rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

If the number of words is not divisible by `n`, push the rest into the last column.

```
static char[][] arrangeVertically(String inputStr, int n) {
    String[] words = inputStr.split("\\s+");
    String input = String.join(" ", words);
    int size = input.length(), wc = words.length / n;
    char[][] matrix = new char[size][n];
    for (char[] row : matrix)
        Arrays.fill(row, ' ');
    int maxRow = 0;
    for (int i = 0, w = 0, r = 0, c = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        if (ch == ' ' && ++w >= wc && c < n - 1) {
            ++c;
            r = w = 0;
        } else {
            matrix[r++][c] = ch;
            maxRow = Math.max(maxRow, r);
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(matrix, 0, maxRow);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputStr =  "Apple is my favorite fruit because it is yummy";

    char[][] v = arrangeVertically(inputStr, 4);

    for (char[] row : v) {
        for (char c : row)
            System.out.print(c + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

output: (n = 4)

```
A m f i 
p y r t 
p   u   
l f i i 
e a t s 
  v     
i o b y 
s r e u 
  i c m 
  t a m 
  e u y 
    s   
    e
```